# Gain tuning issues of op-amp

Tags: gain

I am currently building a simple gain stage with an op-amp (MAX414CPD+-ND) following this circuit diagram

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fonFze.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By adjusting the 10K pot, I am able to amplify the input signal coming out as expected. This is good, however, there are some strange issues I've noticed:

- If I increase the gain to a high value, the output signal gets amplified accordingly. However, if I power down my circuit and power it up again, the output signal is zero. (measuring with respect to ground).
- In order to fix the above issue, I have to power down the circuit, re-adjust the 10K pot to a lower gain value (ie: x2 or x1.5) and power it up again. Afterwards, I see the voltage output is non-zero and amplified accordingly. I can then re-adjust the gain to a higher value.
- I sometimes notice that if I power cycle with a few seconds of delay, the high-gain settings work again at start-up, but the longer I wait in between power cycles the more likely it is that it will not amplify and i'm forced to re-adjust the POT to a lower gain value.
- To summarize: The main issue i'm seeing is that the op-amp cant startup with a "high" gain, I have to start at a lower setting. I took some measurements, it seems like when R2 is set to around 800 ohms this issue occurs (which i believe yields a gain of 5 = R2/R1 +1). Anything lower than this (ie: 400 ohms) then the circuit is able to startup fine and outputting a non-zero signal.

Is there a way to address this or is this a limitation I have to work with? Thoughts/comments appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your inverting and non inverting terminals are swapped. You have positive feed back instead of negative. I'm surprised it's stable at all.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in the diagram, should be fixed now

Comment: The pot, R2, is drawn incorrectly - where does the wiper (moving terminal) connect?

Comment: As you are AC coupling the input, you obviously don't need the same high gain at DC.  A suitable capacitor in series with R1 will reduce the DC gain to unity, which should eliminate this latchup. You want C to be at least R3/R1 * C1 or at least 50 uF.

Comment: @operand, the schematic is improving with each edit. When you're in there again take out the ground symbols on the +5 V and +12 V connections too. Attach the NODE voltage measurements to the wires instead. We'll upvote your question then! :^)

Comment: @BrianDrummond, that's the insight that's missing from my answer! Excellent.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your op-amp is latching up on high gain. Consider what happens on start up. The output is at zero, the + input is at zero (held initially by the capacitor) and the - input is above zero at voltage determined by the divider R1, R2.

$$V- = \frac {5 \cdot R2}{R1 + R2}$$

- input higher than + input will drive the output to negative rail (0 V).

The [data sheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX410-MAX414.pdf) says

> Note 1: The amplifier inputs are connected by internal back-to-back
>   clamp diodes. In order to minimize noise in the input stage, current-
>   limiting resistors are not used. If differential input voltages
>   exceeding ±1.0V are applied, limit input current to 20mA.

I suspect that you're dropping the value of R2 low enough to cause a problem here. Try putting a fixed value resistor in series with R2 to limit the maximum gain.

Edit:

Brian Drummond has commented on the original question:

> As you are AC coupling the input, you obviously don't need the same
>   high gain at DC. A suitable capacitor in series with R1 will reduce
>   the DC gain to unity, which should eliminate this latchup. You want C
>   to be at least R3/R1 * C1 or at least 50 uF.

This is the key insight missing from my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions (@transistor, @Brian Drummond) . A combination of both adding a resistor in series with R2 and a capacitor at R1 (>50 uF) seem to have helped. Can you help me understand the formula R3/R1*C1 you came up with? From my basic undergraduate understanding years ago my intuition tells me that adding a cap would help give a more transient rise in voltage, but why that particular value? Does it have something to do with RC time constants?

Comment: The cap in series reduces the gain at DC, you will essentially build a high-pass filter. The RC combination at the input already is a high-pass filter, its time constant is 1/R3C1. At maximum gain, the time constant of the second high-pass filter is 1/R3C. The formula makes sure that the time Constantin oft the added high-pass filter is higher, so the roll-of frequency is lower. This ensures that the modification  doesn't significantly change the behaviour.